# Preview responsive web components without using iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, responsive-design, preview

I am trying to build a small previewer for my web components. Everything on my page is responsive using media queryies and I'm trying to build a small container where I preview a small fragment of my pages. Just above this container I am putting toggles with different screen widths. When I click one of the toggles my container resizes accordingly and the content inside displays according to what the media query triggers.

The only way I found out how to do this was to use Iframes. It works - but it is a hassle always having to put the content in separate files to link into the src of the iframe. Also - There are issues having to set the iframe height to whatever the content needs.

Currently:

```
<a href="javascript:$('.preview1').attr('width', '320')">320px</a> <!-- etc... -->
<div class="container">
    <iframe class="preview1" src="component1.html" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to trigger a different media query on my container using javascript maybe? Emulating screen resizing?

Comment: Do you know http://jacobrask.github.com/styledocco/? It does exactly this.

Comment: No, I haven't seen that one - it basically does the same as my iframe solution above I guess. Thanks for the inspiration! However, it's still solved by using iframes. Maybe it was solved using a clever technique though, copying in the html using javascript without having to use a src file?